# Magento2.4 How to find storage left on the disk for elastic search

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, elasticsearch, elastic, elasticsearch2

I am facing the following issue on elastic search.

> TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index
> has read-only-allow-delete block

I tried `“cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled” : false` & `“index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete”: null` but still I get the same issue

How to check free space available and the path of the elastic search storage?

I tried `df -h` but I am not sure where the path is located. `rehel-root` shows 98%, Is that the path linked to elastic search?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This path is linked to Elasticsearch, By doing `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v'` you will see the free space available at Elasticsearch.

[image]

Total 49.9GB of disk on the root path that mapping `df -h` directory `/`, 98% of space used.

I cleared a few spaces and it's working now, Have to allocate space or move the project to  /DATA where 2.9TB is available.

[image]

We have three states on Elasticsearch Disk Watermark, Based on your config file this will show, the Flood state is the one where read_only_allow_delete will be enabled by Elasticsearch

- Low disk watermark
- High disk watermark
- Flood stage disk watermark

> ```
> PUT _cluster/settings
> {
>   "transient": {
>    
>     "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "85%",
>     "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "90%",
>     "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "95%",
>     "cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"
>   }
> }
> ```

For more details, you can refer to the link.

```
https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/capacity-planning/elasticsearch-disk-watermark/
https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/capacity-planning/elasticsearch-high-disk-watermark/
```